# Adding address block on Google Map Maker

Tags: google-maps, polygon-creation, address

If it is possible to mark a block of addresses for example B-block, xyz colony, which is a logical block of addresses on Google Mapmaker, how do I do it?

I want to add a polygon feature and select the block but in the options there is no 'block' choice or anything similar.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google Map Maker has Closed: https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/7195127